# React router in subpath is not rendering on link click

Tags: reactjs, url-rewriting, react-router, tuckey-urlrewrite-filter

I have a react application in a subpath (ie: domain.com/login) and when I want to go to someone route I click the link but the Route component dont shows nothing, it works when I write in the browser the route, indeed the home controller shows ok and when I´m in de index of the domain (ie: domain.com) works ok too, the problem is when I click the links in a subpath.
Im using react-router-dom 4 on a java application.

```
import React from "react";
import {render} from "react-dom";
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Link, Route} from "react-router-dom";
const BasicExample = () => (
<Router basename="/login">
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li><Link to="/">Home</Link></li>
            <li><Link to="/about">About</Link></li>
            <li><Link to="/topics">Topics</Link></li>
        </ul>
        <hr/>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
        <Route path="/about" component={About}/>
        <Route path="/topics" component={Topics}/>
    </div>
</Router>
)

const Home = () => (
<div>
    <h2>Home</h2>
</div>
)

const About = () => (
<div>
    <h2>About</h2>
</div>
)

const Topics = ({match}) => (
<div>
    <h2>Topics</h2>
</div>
)

export default BasicExample
render(<BasicExample/>, document.getElementById('login'));
```

this is my urlrewrite.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE urlrewrite PUBLIC "-//tuckey.org//DTD UrlRewrite 4.0//EN"
        "http://www.tuckey.org/res/dtds/urlrewrite4.0.dtd">
<urlrewrite>
    <rule>
        <from>/login/.+</from>
        <to>/login</to>
    </rule>
</urlrewrite>
```

PD. sorry if my english is bad.

Comment: Try wrapping your three routes in a `<Switch>`?

Comment: Yes, I tried but it did not work